# Blank Wordpress admin/dashboard (7 updates pending)

Tags: admin, updates

So...... it's been forever since I've tended to my site from the inside out, I have 7 updates in total.

1 Wordpress update
4 Plug in updates
2 theme updates

Every page of my admin panel is blank (the right parts, I can see the "menu" of the admin panel but not the actual content), so I can't access anything. I'm kind of a newbie to wordpress, I didn't create the site myself, I hired someone to do it for me. But I catch on quick, I just want to do the updates (Without hopefully affecting the theme?) and edit some text from the pages, but I can't do that because the admin panel is blank. Is there anyone who can guide me on what to do and hopefully not f*ck up anything because I can't pull out money for a professional to do this for me, at the moment.

I learn quick, and I'd like to take the least-risky route.

Thank you for your time

A

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing is to backup your entire site if possible. At least backup the database (which you should be able to do from the tools provided by your hosting company.)

Next thing is to start deactivating plugins. Try one at a time... and see if the full admin/dashboard returns. As I guess you can't see the Plugins admin section due to the error you mentioned, you will have to deactivate the plugins via FTP (in /wp-content/plugins/). Renaming each plugin folder will do the trick. Just add a hyphen to the folder name and then reload the WordPress.

*** NB: after a plugin is deactivated, parts of you website will obviously stop functioning as intended. When you reactivate a plugin, you may need to know how to reconfigure them (depending on the plugin) if you don't know, then you might not want to try this method.

If none of this helps,  then you might have to try reinstalling WordPress. Try going to this page: {WordPress web root}/wp-admin/update-core.php 
If you can't see the Re-install Now button, then you will also have to reinstall via FTP.